# Ruby: Test multidimensional hash

Tags: ruby, hash, multidimensional-array

**BACKGROUND**

I have a multidimensional hash which I want to perform a check to ensure that the lookup found a match, but it does not seem to work the same as single dimension hash. My code works for a case where it finds a match, but not for a non-match.  I have read posts in which under certain circumstances the hash will automatically generate a key for a non match, which I think will result in a NIL since I did not specifically set a value.    The error message I get for a non-match case is:

```
can't convert Hash into String (TypeError)
```

**Link to my project for context: https://github.com/elvisimprsntr/siriproxy-redeye**

**Excerpt of code and hyperlinks to source:**

**[redeyeconfig.rb](https://github.com/elvisimprsntr/siriproxy-redeye/blob/master/lib/redeyeconfig.rb)**

```
# Channel number and command syntax to actual RedEye device commandIds
# Note: Must all be lower case. Use multiple entries for variability in Siri response.
@cmdId = Hash.new(&(p=lambda{|h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&p)}))
@cmdId["all"]["cable box"]["0"]         = "/commands/send?commandId=3"
@cmdId["all"]["cable box"]["zero"]      = "/commands/send?commandId=3"
@cmdId["all"]["cable box"]["1"]         = "/commands/send?commandId=4"
```

**[siriproxy-redeye.rb](https://github.com/elvisimprsntr/siriproxy-redeye/blob/master/lib/siriproxy-redeye.rb)**

```
  def send_command(command)
    commandid = @cmdId[@reRoom][@reDevice][command.downcase.strip]
    unless commandid.nil?
        say "OK. Sending command #{command}."
# FIXIT: Does not properly handle no match.  Results in "can't convert Hash into String (TypeError)"
#   This may be due to the fact that dynamically created multidimensional hash will create new keys if a match is not found which will pass the NIL check.
        Rest.get(@reIp[@reSel] + @roomId[@reRoom] + @deviceId[@reRoom][@reDevice] + commandid)
    else
        say "Sorry, I am not programmed for command #{command}."
    end
    request_completed   
  end
```

**QUESTION**

How do I define/initialize my hash differently and/or test for a non-match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get `nil` or a `String` back in case of a failed lookup - instead you get an empty `Hash`.

Check if `commandid.is_a?(Hash)` and `commandid.empty?` to know if the lookup failed or not.

Comment: Ahh right.. since you're always getting a Hash, you can safely ditch the type check :)

Comment: Awesome! I used `unless commandid.empty?` Or do I need to check both?

Comment: lol my answer to your comment is above your question :D (you could have edited the comment instead of deleting and re-posting ist)

Comment: Sorry about that.  Thanks for the clarification.